# No Visible @interface declares the selector 'deleteAllObjects'

Tags: ios, core-data

I am getting this error when I try to delete all of the objects in my Mans CoreData Entity.

```
No visible @interface for 'CoreDataController' declares the selector 'deleteAllObjects:'
```

It is happening as a result of me calling this inside my CoreDataController class.

```
[self deleteAllObjects:@"Mans"];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you declare `deleteAllObjects:` and where do you call it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure your `CoreDataController` class provides a visible declaration that it implements `deleteAllObjects`. In the latest versions of Xcode, methods in the same `@implementation` block should all be visible to each other. Likewise, within the main .m file, there is a class extension; all methods declared there will be visible to methods within the file. In older versions of Xcode any method private to the implementation file had to be declared there as well. If your method is declared in a category, you must make sure to import the category header before referencing it.

Comment: Had a moment.. for some reason I got it in my head deleteAllObjects was a call to something else.. figured it out now thoug.. just writing up the method now :P sorry about that.